# Create DataContext from List<T> rather than from Connection String

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to create `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` from `List<T>`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.105).aspx) it's mandatory to pass a constructor with any connection string to initiate objects.

I am just wondering is there a way to break this and create the context from `List<T>` by extending the `DataContext` or something else?

Expecting something similar Like this,

```
Class TestEntity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<TestEntity>();

list.Add(new TestEntity { EntityId = 1, EntityName = "aaa" });
list.Add(new TestEntity { EntityId = 2, EntityName = "bbb" });

//Creating context on-demand with any available objects rather than external resources (database, file etc.)
var context = new DataContext(list);
```

Comment: DataContext is linked to a database.  So I think you want to crate the database from a List<T>.  A linq is a query and you can't query something that doesn't exist.

Comment: So, Can't I use DataContext in this way?

Comment: DataContext requires connectionString which requires server name and then it gives you a method to created a database, so how do you want to give it by List<T>?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this but remember, it is taking item.EntityName as a Server.

```
 var list = new List<TestEntity>();

        list.Add(new TestEntity { EntityId = 1, EntityName = "aaa" });
        list.Add(new TestEntity { EntityId = 2, EntityName = "bbb" });

        //Creating context on-demand with any available objects rather than external resources (database, file etc.)
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var context = new DataContext(item.EntityName);
            context.CreateDatabase();
        }
```

Output

```
Server=aaa;Database=DataContext;Integrated Security=SSPI
Server=bbb;Database=DataContext;Integrated Security=SSPI
```